# Как отфильтровать данные по запросу? DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Стоит такая задача. Есть модель курсов и у каждого курса свой язык, который выбирается через choices. Как сделать так чтобы пользователь при нажатии на кнопку "Английский" получал курс на английском языке и т.д. По умолчанию загружается русский язык.
Предположим, что наша модель такая:

```
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = [
    ('Ru', 'Русский'),
    ('En', 'Английский'),
 ]

class Course(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField(unique=True)
   lang_course = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='Ru')
```

и есть обычная классовая views.py

```
class CourseDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseDetailSerializer
```

Как мне сделать проверку или как-то по-другому это делается? Я не понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - добавить фильтр.

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class CourseDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Course.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CourseDetailSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['lang_course']
```

Вызов:

```
http://*?lang_course=En
```

Comment: Спасибо.. Сейчас попробую применить и проверить